# Why was Coffee.se created?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites

Why was [*Coffee Stack Exchange*](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) created? Is there any reason, why any question about coffee or coffee-related questions wouldn't be in the scope of [*Seasoned Advice*](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You may want to ask this on Coffee Meta.

Comment: Per the closure reason: This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should pertain to our network or software that drives it as a whole, within the guidelines defined in [help]. You should ask this question on the meta site where your concern originated.

Comment: You might also look at [this discussion at Area 51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/wouldnt-almost-every-question-here-be-on-topic-for-seasoned-advice).

Comment: Over time you'll find that more-and-more specialized sites will pop up, that may seem like sub-sites of existing sites. For example, before [tex.se], most (La)TeX-related questions were posted on [so]. However, now there is a dedicated site for that *specific* nature of questions. I guess [coffee.se] is to [cooking.se] as [tex.se] is to [so].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The site went through the normal Area 51 process - it was created, got enough followers and enough votes on questions, followed by enough committers. And it survived the private beta.

The question you ask, if it wasn't a subset of Seasoned Advice, [*has* been raised on Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/wouldnt-almost-every-question-here-be-on-topic-for-seasoned-advice).

Consensus seems to have been that people were not likely to associate our cooking Q&A with coffee.

Comment: Not to mention that a lot of coffee enthusiasts don't cook.